# virtuoso, how to upload rdf files remotely using isql and ld_dir?

Tags: sparql, rdf, virtuoso

I am trying to upload `*.ttl` files in a virtuoso server using `iSQL` and the function `ld_dir('path','file','graph')`.

If I run the thing in local everything works fine. I add the path in the `DirsAllowed` inside the `virtuoso.ini` config file. Then using the `isql` I run `ld_dir(,,)` and `rdf_loader_run()` and I upload the file.

I would like to do the same thing but from a remote computer. How should I configure the `virtuoso.ini` to allow paths from a remote computer?

Thanks, and sorry for the cross-posting.

Comment: If you load smaller data, then you might try [SPARQL 1.1 Graph Store HTTP Protocol](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-http-rdf-update/); e.g. `curl -X PUT
  --digest -u "dba:dba"
  -H "Content-Type:text/turtle"
  -T data.ttl 
  -G "http://localhost:8890/sparql-graph-crud-auth" --data-urlencode "graph=http://example.com/graph"`

Answer (score 1):

Current versions of Virtuoso do not support loading data files from remote locations. The data file must be accessible through Virtuoso's local filesystem, though it *may* be a remote mount (e.g., NFS), and the containing directory must be included in Virtuoso's `DirsAllowed` setting. Loading from remote locations is planned for a future version.

You'll generally get faster Virtuoso-specific answers by asking on the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users) or the [Virtuoso support forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php)

Comment: Thank you. I will be waiting for that virtuoso update! :)

Comment: This is a very limiting deficiency -- basically, to ingest a TTL file in a remote Virtuoso, you must first SCP it over (or send it some other way)

Comment: @amphibient - There were and are [multiple ways to load local and remote Turtle and other data into Virtuoso](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtRDFInsert).  This question was focused on the [`ld_dir()`](http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/fn_ld_dir/) function which does require filesystem access, though this need not be a local mount (as mentioned, NFS and other remote mount methods work). If none of the documented methods work for you, I encourage you to start a conversation on the [mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users), or ask a new Question!